# SwiftUI - delete row in list with context menu - UI glitch

Tags: ios, swift, listview, swiftui

I've a array of items displayed using `List` in my `SwiftUI View`. I tired to add a `contextMenu` to delete individual items in the `List`. The following is the result.

[image: delteing items from list]

The animation is not what is expected. The row blinks before moving the next one. How to set `animation.right` or something like that so that there is no UI glitch and looks like the default behavior which happens at `onDelete`.

PS: I can't use `onDelete` because, in my app, swiping right and left has other functions.

Here is the code.

```
struct ListDelete: View {
    
    @State var cars = ["Tesla", "Mercedes", "Audi", "Tata", "Jaguar"]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(cars, id: \.self) { car in
            Text(car).contextMenu {
                Button(action: {
                    if let index = self.cars.firstIndex(of: car) {
//                        self.cars.remove(at: index)
                        self.cars.remove(atOffsets: [index])
                    }
                }, label: {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Delete")
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The two approaches used to remove the items from the array, resulted in this same behavior.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Consider putting bounty if no one answers this. I tried looking for solutions actually, but to no avail.

Answer (score 21):

It’s an issue with SwiftUI, hopefully Apple fix it in the next major release.
For now you can solve the issue by adding a small delay before actions are performed in your context button action:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.7){
    //delete row
}
```

Comment: It is a very ugly way to fix it but I found no alternative..

Answer (score 3):

It goes from List, unfortunately ListStyle protocol has any public API. The only way I see now, is mimic List with ScrollView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var cars = ["Tesla", "Mercedes", "Audi", "Tata", "Jaguar"]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(cars, id: \.self) { car in
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    HStack {
                        Text(car).padding()
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .contextMenu {
                        Button(action: {
                            if let index = self.cars.firstIndex(of: car) {
                                    self.cars.remove(at: index)
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Delete")
                                Spacer()
                                Image(systemName: "trash")
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    Divider().padding(.leading)
                }.padding(.bottom, 0) // set -4 to be symetric
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with the following result

[image]

Comment: Your answers fits the question I've asked. But in the requirement of the real app I'm building, we've a section header and a title which goes from large to inline as we scroll. When I implement `ScrollView` instead of a `List` with the header above the `ForEach`, then the header also scrolls along with the `ForEach`, which is not the desired behavior. If I use `VStack` and put the header and `ScrollView` inside it, then the title stays the same when we scroll. Anyways to achieve both?

Comment: is you "list" part of Form ?

Comment: @Imthath you better ask again with simplified snippet which reflect your needs. (I red few seconds before about Section header :-))

Comment: no, my list is not part of a Form. I will post a separate question.

Comment: @Imthath let me know (put the link here)

Answer (score -1):

It is an issue with contextMenu，The blinks is the white background of list item above contextMenu。So you can solve it by make the contextMenu yourSelf