# How to get rid of a glitch when deleting a ForEach item

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `MyObservableObject` showing `[ForEachItem]` and a `ForEachShowTest` view.

When I want to "delete" an item from visibility, I want to do it via contextMenu and setting `show = false`. The issue is, there is a glitch with items overlay for a second. I managed to deal with it via using `DispatchQueue` but now it feels less responsive as it takes time for the item to disappear. Is there any other way?

You can try it yourselves or see a video: we.tl/t-5jMLsTD2dW

view:

```
struct ForEachShowTest: View {
    @ObservedObject var myObservableObject = MyObservableObject()
    var forEachList: [ForEachItem] { myObservableObject.forEachList.filter({ $0.show }) }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(forEachList) { item in
                HStack {
                    Text(item.item)
                    
                }
                .contextMenu {
                    Button("Don't show without glitch") {
                        item.show = false
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(800)) {
                            myObservableObject.updateUI = true
                        }
                    }
                    Button("Don't show with glitch") {
                        item.show = false
                        myObservableObject.updateUI = true
                    }
                }
                
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

ObservableObject:

```
class MyObservableObject: ObservableObject {
    var forEachList: [ForEachItem] = [ ForEachItem(item: "I love ForEach"), ForEachItem(item: "Another list"), ForEachItem(item: "I want to show this one"), ForEachItem(item: "I want to show this one"), ForEachItem(item: "I want to show this one") ]
    @Published var updateUI: Bool = false
    
    init() { }
}

class ForEachItem: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let item: String
    var show: Bool
    
    init(item: String, show: Bool = true) {
        id = UUID()
        self.item = item
        self.show = show
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using "show" to hide it rather than removing it from the array?

Comment: Because in the real app I work even with non-shown data in certain views.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a issue with Swift UI. You get the same behavior with lists too:
[SwiftUI - delete row in list with context menu - UI glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358948/swiftui-delete-row-in-list-with-context-menu-ui-glitch)

If working with a List is an option for you, you may use the .onDelete() modifier for hiding the item without deleting it as a workaround:

```
    List {
        ForEach(forEachList) { item in
            HStack {
                Text(item.item)
                
            }
        }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
            for index in indexSet{
                forEachList[index].show = false
            }
            myObservableObject.updateUI = true
        })
    }
}
```